# Are broken SSH pipes harmful?

Tags: ssh

If I am leaving my computer for an indeterminate amount of time should I exit the SSH session beforehand?

I often see "Broken pipe" when I leave it open and have to SSH in again. This doesn't bother me but I am curious whether it could potentially have any harmful effects on anything if it happens a lot, or if it doesn't matter?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but maybe a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) might be of interest.  Among other helpful features like splitting the screen and handling multiple sessions at once, you can disconnect from a session that keeps running in the background. At a later time, you can SSH in again, reconnect to the session and continue where you left off. Also, there's [byobu](http://byobu.co/), a window manager that runs on top of screen or tmux with some very nice features.

Answer (score 3):

`ssh` connects a client and a server over a TCP socket, and the sockets can be thought of a two way pipe. Whatever you send on one end, will be available on the other, and vice versa.

`Broken Pipe` is a generic socket error message which means the socket has been teared down i.e. the communication pipe is broken. This is not strictly related to `ssh` protocol but to socket and how the connections can be teared down.

It's not harmful *per se*, but any ongoing transfer will be lost, so depending on the value of the transfer you can measure the harmfulness for your case.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` gives the "`Broken pipe`" error message when the connection to the other end drops. Other than having to re-establish the `ssh` session(s), nothing to worry about.